# android AMF protocol

Tags: android, amf

I was looking for some open source libraries, but only what i find was http://www.aftek.com/afteklab/aftek-android-amf-library.shtml but it seems to be dead end. 
If you know some good libraries which support  AMF please share with me.

> According wiki ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_Message_Format )
>   The format is often used in conjunction with Adobe's RTMP to establish
>   connections and control commands for the delivery of streaming media.
>   In this case, the AMF data is encapsulated in a chunk which has a
>   header which defines things as the message length and type (whether it
>   is a "ping", "command" or media data).

So , can I use rtmp library ( ex. http://code.google.com/p/android-rtmp-client/ ) to handle AMF ?

Thx for any help.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Adobe site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dataservicesjee/4.6/Developing/WS4976f0ec3ef48246-1c24bbe312dc391a64f-8000.html#WS4976f0ec3ef48246-44c8a7a912dc3bcf6f2-8000) you need to use flex-messaging-client-android.jar.  Once I started using that file instead of the separate includes it worked fine.

Comment: Hi dkwiebe, from where you get flex-messaging-client-android.jar? I searched lots, but not get any download link.

Comment: As per Adobe on this [page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/enterpriseplatform/10.0/AEPDeveloperGuide/WS4976f0ec3ef48246-1c24bbe312dc391a64f-8000.html) it can be found by following [these instructions](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/enterpriseplatform/10.0/AEPDeveloperGuide/WSe2a127949a92fa1061747727130427d726e-8000.html#WS7dd5c1363434bb706ff094ae12fb22432cf-7fff)